# Normalised vs. denormalised database for similar data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I am planning to build a database where I store a large amount of data about music.
I am storing song-specific information in the `db_song` table.
I'd also like to store *genres*, *instruments*, *samples* and *playlists*.
Because one song can have multiple genres, instruments, samples and playlists, the big question is:

Does it make more sense to:

1. Store all these 4 data in separate tables
2. Store all these 4 data in a single table, and record *type* in separate column

The database will be frequently updated but users will request data even more often.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

As suggested by Amit, with the setup above, there would be a lot of duplicate data.
What about storing genre and instrument values and playlist titles in distinct tables, and genre, instrument and playlist relations (item to song) in yet another 3 tables.

**So the new scenarios:**

1. **Store all these 4 data in separate tables + 4 more tables to store item-to-song relations**
2. **Store all these 4 data in a single table, and record *type* in separate column + relation to song in another column**

Comment: Performance is only one aspect of data duplication.  another aspect is data management itself.  You are going to want much of your data management to be automated.  But there are things you are going to have to do manually.  If you aren't careful, manual processing of millions of rows is going to take up all of your time.  And  unmanaged data rots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'song' can have 0 or 1 or many of each of genres, instruments, samples and playlists.  So it does *not* make sense to have fewer than 5 tables.

Furthermore, many of these are "many-to-many".  For example, one playlist can have many songs; one song can be in many playlists.  To handle such, you need an extra table with song_id and playlist_id to establish the many-to-many 'relationship'.

On the other hand, "genre" is a set of perhaps a dozen possibilities -- 'rock', 'classical', ...  You might not need table for genres.  Instead, each song (and each Playlist?) could include an ENUM or SET with the genre(s).  And it is not worth it to have a many-to-many mapping (in this case).

To help flesh out the schema, think about what the `SELECTs` have to look like.

Answer (score 0):

How much data do you mean when you say "large amount of data"? A few million songs and related metadata should not pose any real performance issue for a standard database setup.

I would recommend designing your database in 3rd Normal Form (3NF) thereby using 4 or more separate tables. With a denormalized structure (one big table), there will be duplicate information in the rows and the updates will be costlier in comparison to the normalized structure.

With the requirements around data reads/analysis, if the requirements are for complex data analysis with historical data requirements then it will be worth considering building a data warehouse on top of the operational system. If the data requirements are simple (joins between these tables to get information for a particular song, artist or genre) then the normalized database should be able to answer them comfortably.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Amit. Could you please have a look at my updated scenarios?

Comment: Also, large amount of data will be maximum a few million rows.

Comment: The 1st approach should be fine.